# Planning nondegree classes

Tags: graduate-school, graduate-admissions

I am thinking of registering for nondegree classes at a local university to give an impression to future admission comitee that my GPA does not really reflect me. But I have some concerns. How should I choose which courses to take.

If some *internationally **known*** professor gives an introductory course e.g. Introduction to Algorithms and if another *internationally **unknown*** one offers advanced graduate course, which one should I choose first ? Consider the future recommendation letters to United States schools I would expect from them.

Comment: Take the graduate-level class **and** do an independent study project with the well-known professor.

Answer (score 5):

The reputation of the faculty member helps somewhat, but is nowhere near as useful as the *quality of the recommendation letter.* A letter from a famous person who doesn't really know you outside of the classroom (or doesn't know you at all) isn't nearly as helpful as an in-depth evaluation from someone you know well, and who knows you well.

However, I find the notion that you would taking an introductory course versus an advanced elective somewhat concerning. In general, if you are looking to buttress a graduate-school application, evidence that you can handle graduate-level work in the field matters far more than having a Big Name write you a weak letter.